# Can't Create Receive Connector

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

So I'm trying to copy a single receive connector from one server to another. I store the receive connector in a variable like so:

```
$NKCRC = Get-ReceiveConnector "<Source Resource Connector>" | Select *
```

Then I try to create the new one with the command below:

```
New-ReceiveConnector -Server $targetServer -Bindings $NKCRC.Bindings -RemoteIPRanges $NKCRC.RemoteIPRanges -Name $NKCRC.Name -TransportRole FrontEndTransport
```

The source RC is an Exchange 2010 RC and I'm creating it on an Exchange 2016 server. When I run the command, I get the following error:

```
The values that you specified for the Bindings and RemoteIPRanges parameters
conflict with the settings on Receive connector "<Identity of receive connector on the 
target server>" SMTP Relay". A Receive connector must have a unique combination of a local 
IP address & port bindings and remote IP address ranges. Change at least one of these
values.
```

I checked the mentioned RC and found they don't have the exact same settings for ANYTHING AT ALL, Bindings or RemoteIPRanges. I'm kinda at a loss. The bindings and RemoteIPRanges for each RC is below:

Source RC Bindings: {0.0.0.0:25}

Count of Source RC RemoteIPRanges: 60 (Rather than post them all, lol)

RC that the Exchange thinks is a duplicate

Bindings: {0.0.0.0:25, 10.200.154.79:25}

Count of Source RC RemoteIPRanges: 50

So obviously they aren't duplicates, right? What am I missing?

Comment: If _any_ of the remote ip ranges are the same this error will trigger because they have to be unique by nature. From the code above you look to be using all of them? Does it work if you don't populate the list as a test?

Comment: Both receive connectors had single IP address entries, one had 50 and the other had 60. It did work if I created it with a single IP address.

Comment: OK, so there appears to be existing ip addresses on existing connectors in the target environment that match your list. Check your existing connectors on 2016 that already have some of those addresses.

Comment: And when I try to copy all the IPs from the source RC to the new connector, I get the same error I was getting before because it thinks there is another receive connector that has the same IP Ranges.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll have to. Geez, lol.

Comment: You should be able to use compare object on the lowerbound and upperbound of the source and potential target to save you from doing a manual search.

Comment: Compare-object showed one IP address in common between the two. I thought as long as you didn't have the exact same set of IPs, receive connectors could share SOME IP addresses?

Comment: They cannot since that is what is used to determine which connector receives the information. Else it would be ambiguous. How would the connectors know which one should take the data if addresses were shared?